# How to return nested collection as array using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get JSON

```
{
 Name: "xyz",
 Roles: [{"Id":1,"Name":"User"},{{"Id":2,"Name":"Mod"}]
}
```

and I have a class Role

```
public class Role
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
}
var roles = db.Role.ToList();
```

and I am trying this way:

```
select new { Name: "xyz", Roles = roles}
```

but that causes an error

*only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context*

Comment: it should be `Name= "xyz"`

Comment: Are you asking how to get a JSON from class instance or how to use a Linq? You can use a `JavaScriptSerializer` or JSON Serializer for that

Comment: `select new { Name: "xyz", Roles = roles}` and what is this? Is that your actual code or part of it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a JSON serializer to serialise the object into JSON. 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
var roles = ...
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(roles);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it is working.

```
var items = new List<Role>();
            items.Add(new Role() { Id = 1 , Name = "Admin" });
            var username = "test";
            var newOvj = new { username = username, roles = items };
            var stringdata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newOvj);
```